# Mobile Site is zoomed in a little on-loading

Tags: mobile, browser, viewport

So I'm trying to figure out why my site isn't loading on mobile correctly, it is zooming in just so slightly, I can zoom out with my finger and it looks correctly, I have everything at 100% width. Also when I look at it in chrome and safari developer mode on responsive mode it looks correct it only looks bad on an actual mobile browser.

The site is at http://risewomensconference.org all help and ideas appreciated. I tried multiple viewport meta changes and I think I have it correct.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- it's hard to solve a problem without seeing it. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Your site seems to load correctly for me on Chrome Android, no zoom out possible.